# JavaScript key value generation in XSLT

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to generate output like this through XSL:

```
<script>
    var quickCatalogueCategories = {
        for each values do {
            '{title}': 'http://www.news.com/{search key}',
        }
    };
</script>
```

The problem is I am getting the output but **after each title I should get url** instead after all titles I am getting the URL. Even after the URL I should have only one key but continuously displaying all four keys.

Can you tell me how to fix it?

Trying to achieve output like this:

```
<script>
    var quickCatalogueCategories = {
        '{What's New}':'http: //www.news.com/{news}',
        '{Featured}':'http: //www.news.com/{featured}',
        '{Most Delivered}':'http: //www.news.com/{most-delivered}',
        '{Online Only}':'http: //www.news.com/{online-only}',
    }
</script>
```

Comment: hi, if you find my answer below useful, please accept it by clicking the check mark (just below the arrowheads).

Comment: @JoelM.Lamsen: Is there any link for xsl css reference guide

Comment: you can try this one (http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-XSL-and-CSS)

Comment: @JoelM.Lamsen: can you reply to this plshttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/22084693/missing-second-p-tag-how-to-get-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <!-- Skin: Default XSL -->
    <!--xsl:include href="http://www.interwoven.com/livesite/xsl/HTMLTemplates.xsl"/-->
    <!--xsl:include href="http://www.interwoven.com/livesite/xsl/StringTemplates.xsl"/-->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!-- TODO put section -->
        <script>
            var quickCatalogueCategories={
            <xsl:for-each select="//Datum[@Name='Catalog']//CatalogContainer">
                <!-- you are already in the node, just select the value of the children -->
                <xsl:text>&#x9;'{</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="CatalogKey"/><xsl:text>'}</xsl:text>:'http://www.news.com/{'<xsl:value-of select="CatalogView"/>}',}
            </xsl:for-each>
            }            
        </script>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```