# missing second p tag how to get it

Tags: html, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am not getting the second p tag in my xsl...
providing my code below...

http://xsltransform.net/b4GWV9/17

```
<xsl:for-each select="child::*">
    <xsl:if test="normalize-space(.)!=''">
    <p class="specifications__value-title">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </p>                                            
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

providing my html output also below

http://jsfiddle.net/F9wh7/

```
<li class="specifications__value">
    <p class="specifications__value-title">Dimensions</p>
     **<p class="specifications__value-copy">5.38 x 2.75 x 0.31 inches</p>**
</li>
```

Comment: Folks are unlikely to follow your links, especially as they seem unlikely to persist. Posting a _minimal_ example of a stylesheet and input document which demonstrates your problem here, as part of your question, may get your more help sooner. (By minimal I mean trim away everything that's not absolutely required to demonstrate the issue.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change

```
<xsl:for-each select="child::*[name()!='SpecificationsHeading']">
```

into

```
<xsl:for-each select="descendant::*[name()!='SpecificationsHeading']">
```

I also noticed in your output that there are two `<p class="specifications__value-title">`. Maybe you meant the other one to be `<p class="specifications__value-copy">`.

Comment: can you pls reply to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22179798/xsl-data-attribute-not-getting-value-showirorng-er