# xsl data attribute not getting value showirorng > er

Tags: html, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to pass this value in data attribute but I don't know how to retrieve in XSL. Without putting it in data attribute, I am getting the value.

http://xsltransform.net/bFukv8i/9

Providing a snippet of my XSL code below:

```
<article class="banner-hero banner-hero--blocks" data-nav-title="<xsl:value-of select='//Devices//SideMenu//NavTitle'/>"></article>
        <script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `<article class="banner-hero banner-hero--blocks" data-nav-title="{//Devices//SideMenu//NavTitle}"></article>`, that is called an attribute value template.

Comment: thanks for your reply but still getting the other error http://xsltransform.net/bFukv8i/12

Comment: You have `<!--<article class="banner-hero banner-hero--blocks"` which is not allowed in XML, you are not allowed the `--` inside the comment so you need to fix that.

Comment: thanks for your reply...its working now but dont know how to pass this if condition inside my data-nav-title attribute       <xsl:if test="//Devices//SideMenu//NavTitleCheckBox='SideMenu'">     
        Data_Nav_Title="<xsl:value-of select='//Devices//SideMenu//NavTitle'/>"
    </xsl:if>   http://xsltransform.net/bFukv8i/16

Comment: I suggest you start a new question for a new issue instead of raising a new question in comments.

Comment: I updated my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22180593/if-condition-inside-data-attribute-of-html-using-xsl pls help