# if condition inside data attribute of html using xsl

Tags: html, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am trying to write an if condition inside my data attribute...
right now I am receiving the xsml vaue but dont know how to put if there...
when i use if outside html it works fine..
providing my code below...

http://xsltransform.net/bFukv8i/16

```
<xsl:if test="//Devices//SideMenu//NavTitleCheckBox='SideMenu'">     
        Data_Nav_Title="<xsl:value-of select='//Devices//SideMenu//NavTitle'/>"
    </xsl:if>



    <article class="banner-hero banner-hero--blocks" data-nav-title="{//Devices//SideMenu//NavTitle}"></article>
        <script>
```

Comment: Have a look at `xsl:attribute`.

Comment: Do not tag a question with both `xslt-1.0` and `xslt-2.0`. These tags are meant to be exclusive.

Answer (score 2):

using XSL 2.0, you can do this

```
<article class="banner-hero banner-hero--blocks" data-nav-title="{if (//Devices//SideMenu//NavTitleCheckBox='SideMenu') then //Devices//SideMenu//NavTitle else ()}">
    </article>
```

Comment: Oh! Darn! That makes things easy! I have been using select / choose syntax in order to have an if + else type of feature.

Comment: @joel: can you reply to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22214316/backbone-app-not-calling-in-xsl-but-works-fine-in-my-local